# I forgot to add brown sugar to my chocolate chip cookies......and didn't realize I forgot the brown sugar until it was done cooking

Tags: cookies

I remembered everything else, it taste fine but a little bland. Even though i already cooked it, is there anything I can do to make it taste better?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't change the cookies themselves! You could frost them, though, and you can get as much sugar as you want in that way.

You could also try to integrate them into something else, possibly crumbled up. I could see them being good in/on ice cream, or maybe as a cheesecake topping or even crust, or in a parfait. In general, things that have sweetness on their own but could do with some texture would probably work.

Comment: I agree, once baked the only way you'd be able to add flavor to the inside would be to use a solvent, ie water, and that would turn them to mush. Dipping them in or drizzling chocolate on them would be a good way to add some sweetness.

Comment: Ice cream came to mind immediately for me.  Fair taste but bland, crumbled with it as suggested, or maybe as mini-ice-cream sandwiches.  If want a bit more punch a caramel sauce yells that it could offset for some of the missing sugar.