# Forgot to add Sugar in cookie dough . Is there any way to add sugar?

Tags: cookies, brown-sugar

While adding ingredients to mixture(for cookies), I forgot to put brown sugar.. 
Now that when i've baked cookies, what alternate can I add to retain their taste?

Comment: Was the brown sugar the only sweetener in the recipe ?

Comment: Frosting?  Filling/cooking sandwiches?  Ice cream sandwiches? Are you intent on using them as a cookie, or are you open to other applications?

Comment: 'Crumble it up on top of ice cream' is always an option.  Or fruit.  Maybe even a crumb topping for a cobbler, or a crumb crust for a pie.

Comment: **@Joe** I would say that one qualifies as an answer...

Comment: **@moscafj** Your comment is getting upvoted, so I would say it qualifies as an answer...

Comment: **@Both:** ping me here after you've posted an answer and I'll come back and upvote.  **0:-)**

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81303/i-forgot-to-add-brown-sugar-to-my-chocolate-chip-cookies-and-didnt-realize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never be able to get sweetness into them in the same way as if you had added sugar to begin with, but you do have other options.

- As Fabby said, you can add sweet things to them now which will result in a sweet topping (or sandwitch!).
- Depending on the type of cookie (it would work better with soft cookies) you could try crumbling them up and mixing with icing to make a "cake pop" (cake pops are made by crumbling cake and mixing with icing).

Other non-cookie options:

- You could crumble them and mix with some butter (to hold it together) and sugar/sweetener and use to line a pie/crumble/bars.
- You could embrace the savoury and eat them as savoury biscuits - warm or toast them and top with butter or cheese or something. (Garlic butter?)

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of things you can add to them after the fact:

- Icing
- Jam
- Crème au beurre with lots of sugar
- Whipped cream with 2 packs of vanilla sugar instead of one
- Grated chocolate
- Honey
- ...

With some of the above (like jam, chocolate and honey), you can put them into the oven again at a low temperature (50°C / 120°F) and get a unique cookie!